# large app ram usage and doesn't decrease

Tags: android

When my app starts, it uses 31 mb of ram as stated on  the settings. The first activity of my app has a viewpager that holds 3 drawables (about 200kb per image) and runs a push service on start. I tried to start a less-expensive activity and the ram usage went to 40mb.

I've got a few questions for this:

1. Is the 31mb of ram normal for an android app?
2. Why does the ram usage increase when starting a activity that uses
   less ram? If the resources were not deleted, what keeps them alive?

Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActionBar().hide();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkIfCookiesExist();
        setupViewPager();
        }

    public void signIn(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginDialog.class));
    }

    private void setupViewPager() {
        List<Integer> images = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.bg1, R.drawable.bg2, R.drawable.bg3);
        Collections.shuffle(images);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(images);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
        circleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void checkIfCookiesExist() {
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("Session", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)){
        PersistentCookieStore mCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(
                getApplicationContext());
        List<Cookie> cookies = mCookieStore.getCookies();
        for (Cookie c : cookies) {
            if (c.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuAct.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And the PagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private List<Integer> images;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(List<Integer> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        img.setImageResource(images.get(position));
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

}
```

Comment: 31 MB is doesn't look normal!

Did you tried with just 1 images? how much is RAM usage with just 1 image? this might help to drill down the problem.

Do you really need to override onBackPressed()?

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: 200 KB is the filesize of the images and is unrelated to their footprint when uncompressed into memory. If you show the middle view in the viewpager, viewpager may load all 3 images at the same time. So the first order of business is to let us know what's the size of the 3 images you are using?

Comment: @Kai if I were to load up say 300 10kb images of 120x70px resolution and have them in RAM, (to quickly display thumbnails) would Android be able handle it? ...assuming it runs on a dual-core/quad-core hardware like kindle fire or nexus.

Comment: @Srikanth Without scaling, each one takes about 33k, so 300 would be 10MB.  That's a lot, given that the heap on many Android devices is 16MB.  You might want to think about some form of cacheing, since the user cannot see 300 at one time, I assume.

Comment: @Srikanth it depends on how much memory the device allows for each process, the memory may go from 16MB for circa-2009 Android phones to 256MB for Nexus 7 (2013). Once you know the amount of allowed RAM on device, calculate what amount of RAM these images require: 300*12*70*4(4 bytes per pixel)=10,080,000~=10MB (not including the small overhead for each Java object). You may or may not need to worry about running out of RAM depending on device. If you use image-loading frameworks, most of them provide facility for you to tweak the amount of RAM they can use to cache images in RAM.

Comment: @Simon The number of images are fixed and user can quickly switch over to different fragments (- its a fixed restaurant menu with a listview of thumbnails for each category of food). So, I was thinkin of loading images once on boot.

Comment: @Kai Thanks. I didn't know that RAM allocation size for a process can vary. I was of the opinion that it varies with the version of Android being run, irrespective of device's RAM.

Comment: @Srikanth I recommend reading http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html, especiall the section "Check how much memory you should use"

Comment: Im using a fullscreen viewpager. I tried to use MAT and it shows that BitmapShader has the highest heap. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: I tried deleting the 2 drawables of the viewpager and the ram usage dropped to 13 MB. The images' size is 864x572